# Reading the values of selected cells in Excel inside a VB.NET addin

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio

How to read the selected cells' values within a VB.NET addin for Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
    Sub test()
    Dim curCell As Range 'will be used to iterate through the selected range
    Dim myRange As Range 'variable to represent the selected range
    Set myRange = Application.Selection
    For Each curCell In myRange.Cells 'Here is where you iterate through the selection
        MsgBox (curCell.Value) 
       'I simply create a message box to print each cell value. 
       'You would process as appropriate to your business problem
    Next curCell

    End Sub
```